# How to rotate a table's column items to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table and it needs to change

```
Key                  Value
CapacityColdBTU      2000
PowerLevelCold       B
Inverter/Standard    Standard
CapacityColdBTU      1500
PowerLevelCold       B
Inverter/Standard    Inverter
```

The table should look like below before I use it. I cannot use the table in searching with more than 1 criteria. How do I change it?

```
CapacityColdBTU   PowerLevelCold    Inverter/Standard
2000              B                 Inverter
```

Thank you

Comment: Does the table only contain one entity or is there a foreign key or something to tell that it's part of a single entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `PIVOT`:

```
select *
from
(
  select [key], value
  from yourtable
) x
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for [key] in ([CapacityColdBTU], [PowerLevelCold], [Inverter/Standard])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/228d3/3)

Or you can use a `CASE` statement with aggregate, note this version generates the result you have listed with the `Inverter` value in the `[Inverter/Standard]` field:

```
select 
  max(case when [key] = 'CapacityColdBTU' 
        then value end) as CapacityColdBTU,
  max(case when [key] = 'PowerLevelCold' 
        then value end) as PowerLevelCold,
  min(case when [key] = 'Inverter/Standard' 
        then value end) as [Inverter/Standard]
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/228d3/6)

If you have an `id` or some field that identifies each of these fields with a main record, then you can display the values for each id.

Comment: The OP had 'Inverter' as the value selected, max() gives you 'Standard'.  Not that the desired logic is very clear either...

Comment: @PinnyM then they would need to use the second version with the `case` and aggregate. My guess is they have some unique id to associate each of these values with a main record, once that is in place this would resolve itself.